# How to fix "No module named 'encodings'"

Tags: python

Before today, I only had a `Python37-32` directory when it comes to python. I had to install python 2.7 for something, and now everything has broken.

After downloading the latest python release and clicking "update current installation" (or something along these lines), I was expecting I would have my old python back. However, I am now missing all of my imports. When trying to reinstall them with `py -m pip install <package>`, I ran into **this:**

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Whenever I typed "py" into my VScode terminal (and normal command prompt), I would get this error. What have I accidentally done to mess up everything?

Comment: Have you checked your computer's  environment variables?

Comment: Yes -- I added in my `C:\....\Python\Python37` as well as `Python37\Scripts` on my User Variables. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: you have to check if python2.7 is in your path as well. I have this feeling your py is referring to python 2 since the error did throw back that it cannot find a module named 'encoding'.

Comment: I don't see it; and my System Variables path doesn't either. I think I messed up my variables big time -- I'm honestly lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I didn't "fix" my problem

I decided I should uninstall both Python2.7 and Python3.7, then reinstall the latest version. I have. It's working fine now, albeit I will need to reinstall many packages!